# Unresolved Reference: mockwebserver

Tags: android-studio, junit4, okhttp, mockwebserver

I'm writing a test suite with [mockwebserver](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver). I entered all of the dependencies from the official github page.  Every time I try to run the test I receive `Unresolved reference: mockwebserver`

There's no option to import.  The lettering isn't red on the import.  Android Studio doesn't prompt anything.  There are no other errors aside from ones related to the unresolved reference.

Screenshot:
[image]

---

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions")
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    useLibrary("android.test.runner")
    useLibrary("android.test.base")
    useLibrary("android.test.mock")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.moviespotter"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        compose true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver3:5.0.0-alpha.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0' //Glide
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.1"
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is in androidTest, it should be

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver3:5.0.0-alpha.2'
```

Also mixing 5.0.0-alpha.2 and 4.3.1 is a world of hurt.

Comment: Which versions would you recommend?  I was trying out different combos until I found one that worked.

Comment: Just use 4.9.2 for everything, it's the most recent stable release.

Answer (score -1):

I found the culprit.

When adding the dependency to the build.gradle file it should read `implementation`.

Change From:
`testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver3:5.0.0-alpha.2'`

To:
`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver3:5.0.0-alpha.2'`

Comment: implementation is too high, it's accidentally fixing it by making it a dependency of src/main, while you want it to be included just for tests.